# How to properly animate a Slider in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, animation, swiftui, slider, swiftui-animation

I want to animate a `Slider` whenever its `value` changes with a custom animation (with a custom duration). But somehow it doesn't work. No matter what `animation` I specify, it always uses the same (very short) animation that is almost not noticeable.

Here's a minimal code example:

```
struct SliderView: View {
    @State var value: Float = 0

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Slider(value: $value)
                .animation(.linear(duration: 3), value: value) // ← here 
            Button("Toggle") {
                value = value < 0.5 ? 1 : 0
            }
        }
        .frame(width: 300, height: 200)
        .padding(16)
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

***Note 1:*** Without the `animation` modifier, I get no animation at all and the knob immediately jumps to its new position. With the modifier, it animates but it doesn't seem to respect the concrete animation I specify.

***Note 2:*** I know that I could use an explicit animation and wrap the change in a `withAnimation` closure. But even if that worked, it's not an option for me because the in my concrete case, the `value` is not a `@State` but a `@Binding` and is thus set externally from a view model that should not know anything about SwiftUI.

Comment: Raised this with an Apple engineer during Q&A. They confirmed that this is likely a bug. Filed a feedback: [FB11802261](https://openradar.appspot.com/FB11802261)

Comment: No, like I said: It's a confirmed bug. You can't fix it unless Apple fixes it.